# Why is there a gap when text added into div?

Tags: html, vertical-alignment, css

When I add text to textboxsquare it adds a space above the Div why is this and how do i go about making it so that there is none of this space and just stays in line with the other?
http://jsfiddle.net/wK6dp/1/

CSS

```
#textbox {
   border: 1px solid #848484;
   -moz-border-radius-topleft: 30px;
   -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 30px;
   border-top-left-radius: 30px;
   -moz-border-radius-topright: 30px;
   -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 30px;
   border-top-right-radius: 30px;
   outline:0;
   height:auto;
   display: block;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 300px;
   padding-left:20px;
   padding-right:20px;
   background-color: #f47924;
   margin: 0px;
   font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
   text-align:center;
   color:white;
}

#textboxSquare {
   display:inline-block;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   border: 1px solid #848484;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="textbox">
    <h3>John Smith</h3>
</div>
<div id="textboxSquare"></div>
   <div id="textboxSquare">
       Copy Pasta pasta <br />
       Copy Pasta pasta <br />
       Copy Pasta pasta <br   />
       Copy Pasta pasta<br />
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `vertical-align:top`:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/wK6dp/3/)

```
#textboxSquare {
display: inline-block;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border: 1px solid #848484;
vertical-align: top;    /*   added   */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cannot use the same id name twice in your mark up. Secondly, if you are using `display:inline-block`, add a `vertical-align:top;` to get your thing to work.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wK6dp/4/)**

**The CSS Change:**

```
.textboxSquare {
display:inline-block;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border: 1px solid #848484;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

***PS: I have changed your `id` into `class` for semantics.***